# Calculate Sum of Several Rows and Create Bar Graph Excel

Tags: excel, graph, excel-formula

I have a large set of values:
ID HOURS
29  9
29  9
29  8
29  9
29  10
29  9
29  9
29  7
29  9
29  9
29  8
29  10
29  8
29  9
29  9
29  8
29  9
29  10
29  9
29  9
29  8
29  6
29  9
29  9
29  6
29  9
29  8
29  9
29  9
29  8
29  9
29  9
29  8
29  9
29  9
29  9
29  8
29  10
29  9
29  7
29  10
29  8.5
29  8.5
29  7.5
29  7
29  6
29  9
29  8.5
29  10
29  9
29  8.5
29  9
29  9
29  8
29  8.5
29  8
29  9
29  8.5
29  8.5
29  10
29  8
29  7.5
29  7.5
29  7.5
29  9
29  7.5
29  9
29  10
29  10
29  8.5
29  7.5
29  8
29  8.5
29  9.5
29  7
29  9.5
29  9
29  8.5
29  8.5
29  7.5
29  8
29  8
29  8.5
29  9
29  8.5
29  9
29  9
29  8.5
29  9
29  10
29  9
29  8.5
29  9
29  7
29  9
28  7
28  8
28  9
28  8
28  7
28  9
28  9
28  9
28  8
28  9
28  9
28  8
28  9
28  9
... all the way to ID 1
There is a random number of hours for every ID, and I have to create a bar graph that sums up the values of each ID and displays them in a bar graph. I am very new to excel, how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say your id's are in column A, cells A1:A500, and your hours are in B1:B500.
Type out numbers 1-29 in a column, say in cells c1:c29. In cell D1, you can type =sumif($A$1:$A$500,C1, $B$1:$B$500).

Basically this sums the values in column B, if the values in column A equal C1.  Now you can drag the formula down for all 29 values.  From there, just graph.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this using a PivotChart.

Highlight the range of your data and choose Insert | PivotChart.

Choose a location for the chart.

Drag the ID field into the Axis Fields box and the Hours field into the ∑ values box.

You should get something like this.

[image]